# Handling temporarily null reference types when deserializing objects in C# 8.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I am trying C# 8.0 out, and I want to enable the null reference checking for the entire project. I am hoping I can improve my code design, and without disabling the nullability context in any code scopes.

I encountered a problem when I deserialize an object graph. The objects have references with one another but, for the final user view, all references in the object graph *must* have a value.

In other words, during the deserialization process, references *may* be `null`, but after all objects have finished loading, a final process will link all of the objects together, thus resolving those `null` references.

### Workarounds

I have been able to address this using a few different techniques, and they each work as expected. They also expand the code considerably, however, by introducing a lot of extra scaffolding.

#### Option #1: Shadow Class

For example, I tried writing a paired class for each kind of object, using these as an intermediate object during deserialization. In these paired classes, all reference are allowed to be `null`. After deserialization completes, I copy all fields from these classes and convert them to the real object. Of course, with this approach, I need write a *lot* of extra code.

#### Option #2: Shadow Members

Alternatively, I tried to put a nullable field and a non-nullable property. This is similar to the previous approach, but I'm using paired members instead of paired classes. Then I add an internal setter for each field. This approach has less code than the first, but it still increases my code base considerably.

#### Option #3: Reflection

Traditionally, without considering performance, I would have managed deserialization using reflection so that there’s almost has no extra code on a per class basis. But writing my own parsing code has some benefits—for example, I can output more useful error messages including tips on how callers can resolve issues.

But when I introduce the nullable fields, my parsing code increases considerably—and with the sole purpose of satisfying the code analysis.

### Sample Code

For the sake of demonstration, I simplified the code as much as possible; my actual classes obviously do much more than this.

```cs
class Person
{
    private IReadOnlyList<Person>? friends;

    internal Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Person> Friends => this.friends!;

    internal SetFriends(IReadOnlyList<Person> friends)
    {
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}

class PersonForSerialize
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<string> Friends { get; set; }
}

IReadOnlyList<Person> LoadPeople(string path)
{
    PersonForSerialize[] peopleTemp = LoadFromFile(path);
    Person[] people = new Person[peopleTemp.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleTemp.Count; ++i)
    {
        people[i] = new Person(peopleTemp[i].Name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < peopleTemp.Count; ++i)
    {
        Person[] friends = new Person[peopleTemp[i].Friends.Count];
        for (int j = 0; j < friends.Count; ++j)
        {
            string friendName = peopleTemp[i].Friends[j];
            friends[j] = FindPerson(people, friendName);
        }

        people[i].SetFriends(friends);
    }
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to satisfy the null reference checking in C# 8.0 for properties that are only temporarily null during deserialization without introducing a lot of extra code for every class?

Answer (score 14):

You’re concerned that while your objects aren't *intended* to have `null` members, those members will inevitably be `null` during the construction of your object graph.

Ultimately, this is a *really* common problem. It affects, yes, deserialization, but also the creation of objects during e.g., mapping or data binding of e.g. data transfer objects or view models. Often, these members are to be null for a very brief period between constructing an object and setting its properties. Other times, they might sit in limbo during a longer period as your code e.g. fully populates a dependency data set, as required here with your interconnected object graph.

Fortunately, Microsoft has addressed this *exact* scenario, offering us two different approaches.

#### Option #1: Null-Forgiving Operator

The first approach, as [@andrew-hanlon notes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55009807/3025856), is to use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). What may not be immediately obvious, however, is that you can use this *directly* on your non-nullable members, *thus entirely eliminating your intermediary classes* (e.g., `PersonForSerialize` in your example). In fact, depending on your exact business requirements, you might be able to reduce your `Person` class down to something as simple as:

```cs
class Person
{

    internal Person() {}

    public string Name { get; internal set; } = null!; 

    public IReadOnlyList<Person> Friends { get; internal set; } = null!;

}
```

#### Option #2: Nullable Attributes

> ***Update:*** As of .NET 5.0.4 (SDK 5.0.201), which shipped on March 9th, 2021, the below approach will now yield a `CS8616` warning. Given this, you are better off using the null-forgiving operator outlined above.

The second approach gives you the *same exact results*, but does so by providing hints to Roslyn's static flow analysis via [nullable attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes). These require more annotations than the null-forgiving operator, but are also more explicit about what's going on. In fact, I actually *prefer* this approach just because it's more obvious and intuitive to developers otherwise unaccustomed to the syntax.

```cs
class Person
{

    internal Person() {}

    [NotNull, DisallowNull]
    public string? Name { get; internal set; }; 

    [NotNull, DisallowNull]
    public IReadOnlyList<Person>? Friends { get; internal set; };

}
```

In this case, you're explicitly acknowledging that the members *can* be `null` by adding the nullability indicator (`?`) to the return types (e.g., `IReadOnlyList<Person>?`). But you're *then* using the nullable attributes to tell consumers that *even though the members are marked as nullable*:

- `[NotNull]`: A nullable return value will *never* be null.
- `[DisallowNull]`: An input argument should never be null.

#### Analysis

<s>Regardless of which approach you use, the end results are the same.</s> Without the null-forgiving operator on a non-nullable property, you would have received the following warning on your members:

> `CS8618`: Non-nullable property 'Name' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

Alternatively, without using the `[NotNull]` attribute on a nullable property, you would have received the following warning when attempting to assign its value to a non-nullable variable:

> `CS8600`: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

Or, similarly, upon trying to call a member of the value:

> `CS8602`: Dereference of a possibly null reference.

Using one of these two approaches, however, you can construct the object with default (`null`) values, while still giving downstream consumers confidence that the values will, in fact, not be `null`—and, thus, allowing them to consume the values without necessitating guard clauses or other defensive code.

Conversely, when using either of these approaches, you *will* still get the following warning when attempting to assign a `null` value to these members:

> `CS8625`: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.

That's right: You'll *even get that when assigning to the `string?` property* because that's what the `[DisallowNull]` is instructing the compiler to do.

#### Conclusion

It’s up to you which of these approaches you take. As they both yield the same results, it’s a purely stylistic preference. Either way, you’re able to keep the members `null` during construction, while still realizing the benefits of C#’s non-nullable types.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your question boils down to:

**How do I avoid compiler warnings**

> `CS8618`: Non-nullable property 'Name' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

**for simple model classes which are used for serialization?**

You can solve the problem by creating a default constructor for which you suppress the warning. Now you want to make sure that this constructor is only used by your deserialization routine (e.g. `System.Text.Json` or Entity Framework). To avoid unintentional use add annotation `[Obsolete]` with parameter `error=true` which would raise compiler error [CS0618](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0618).

As code:

```
public class PersonForSerialize
{
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
    [Obsolete("Only intended for de-serialization.", true)]
    public PersonForSerialize()
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
    {
    }

    // Optional constructor
    public PersonForSerialize(string name, IReadOnlyList<string> friends)
    {
        Name = name;
        Friends = friends;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<string> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

Note1: You can let Visual Studio auto-generate the optional constructor using a quick action.

Note2: If you really mean to use the constructor marked as obsolete, you need to remove the `error=true` parameter. Now you can suppress the warning when calling the parameter-less constructor via `#pragma warning disable CA1806`.

Comment: That’s an interesting approach. Obviously, the optional constructor may become cumbersome if there are a large number of properties—and, thus, corresponding parameters. But, as you imply, that constructor isn’t even necessary if these classes will exclusively be constructed by the deserializer. I don’t love the idea of maintaining an “obsolete” constructor with a suppression, but in some ways it’s more honest and explicit about what’s going on by acknowledging the disconnect and documenting it with the `[Obsolete()]` attribute and the `#pragma` directive. This is a nice addition to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

While certainly *highlighted* due to non-nullable defaults in C# 8, this is really a common 'circular dependency' problem that has always existed with interdependent construction.

As you found, one standard solution is to use a restricted setter. With C# 8, you may want to use a *'null-forgiving'* `null!` during deserialization of the object graph - allowing you to differentiate an unconstructed set from a valid empty set, and minimize allocation.

Example:

```
class Person
{
    internal Person(string name, IReadOnlyList<Person> friends)
    {
        Name = name; Friends = friends
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Person> Friends {get; internal set;}
}

class SerializedPerson { ... } // Class no longer specifically required. 

IEnumerable<Person> LoadPeople(string path)
{
    var serializedPeople = LoadFromFile(path);
    
    // Note the use of null!
    var people = serializedPeople.Select(p => new Person(p.Name, null!));
    
    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        person.Friends = GetFriends(person, people, serializedPeople);
    }

    return people;
}
```

Comment: With this approach, you no longer need the intermediate `SerializedPerson` class (what the OP labeled `PersonForSerialize`). You’re not actually using it, but as it was still present in the code, I had overlooked that the first time I read this answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks, that's a good point. Always appreciate someone reviewing older answers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would serialise your graph structure without Name+IdsOnly class especially if a person has plenty properties, but this is out of scope.

## Nullability of Friends

Nulls in `Friends` could be addressed by always having the list.

For example:

```
public List<Person> Friends { get; set; } = new List<Friends>();
```

## Partly populated objects that look like they're null safe

If you're using Json.NET you could take advantage of JsonConstructor.

Please note with this approach you can end up with null in Person unless you protect against it in the constructor.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; 

class Person
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    internal Person(
        string name, 
        List<Person> friends)
    {
        Name = name; // Can end up being null if left without '?? "No name"';
        Friends = friends ?? new List<Person>();
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }

    public void AddFriends(IEnumerable<Person> friends)
    {
        Friends.AddRange(friends);
    }
}
```

This should handle all kinds of data:

```
Deserialise<Person>("{}");
Deserialise<Person>("{ 'Name': 'John'}");
Deserialise<Person>("{ 'Name': 'John', 'Friends': [] }");
Deserialise<Person>("{ 'Name': 'John', 'Friends': [ {'Name': 'Jenny'}]}");
Deserialise<Person>("{ 'Friends': [{'Name': 'Jenny'}]}");
```

All above examples should produce a `Person` object. You could then do validation and fill in the missing details.

Comment: This is also a good approach. I like that the introduction of `AddFriends()` allows an `IEnumerable<Person>` to be passed, without needing to _replace_ the `Friends` list. And even aside from constructing graphs, I often find it useful to implement a `[JsonConstructor]` to carefully control the deserialization process. It’s worth noting that, as of .NET 5, [an attribute of the same name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconstructorattribute) is available for the `System.Text.Json` serialization built into .NET, should you prefer that over Json.NET.

Comment: One Suggestion: With `AddFriends()`, you can remove the setter for the `Friends` property. That resolves having a settable collection property, which the [Roslyn Code Analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers) will rightfully warn you about (with a [CA2227](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2227)), assuming you have them fully enabled. I hacked around this by using an `internal` setter in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133446/3025856), but you can remove this entirely with your approach.